# Not authorized to access the supplied tenant specific endpoint

Tags: marketing-cloud

I just downloaded the latest FuelSDK 1.1 (in .Net) and try to simply create ETClient. I pass in correct clientId and clientSecret however I got null exception in ((UserInfo)userInfo.Get()

Here is the exception:

> {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"Not authorized to
>   access the supplied tenant specific
>   endpoint","error_uri":"https://example.com"}

With the same clientId and clientSecret, I'm able to create ET_Client just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As described in documentation available in the [github repo](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp), starting from v1.1.0 you have to specify your tenant's endpoints either in the `parameters` ETClient constructor variable or in the **App.config** file** which definition is below :

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="fuelSDK" type="FuelSDK.FuelSDKConfigurationSection, FuelSDK" />
  </configSections>
  <fuelSDK 
    appSignature="<appSignature>" 
    clientId="<clientId>" 
    clientSecret="<clientSecret>" 
    authEndPoint="<authenticationEndPoint>" 
    soapEndPoint="<soapEndPoint>" 
    restEndPoint="<restEndPoint>" />
</configuration>
```

- `SoapEndPoint` can be found in the Administration tab
- `appSignature`, `clientId`, `ClientSecret`, `authenticationEndPoint` and `restEndPoint` can be found in : Administration > Account > Installed Packages

** : Please check the github repo for more information about the config file

Comment: Yes, I passed in SoapEndPoint , authendpoint and restendpoint like this:
{"soapEndPoint", "https://...marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx"},
{"authEndPoint", "https://...auth.marketingcloudapis.com/"},
{"restEndPoint", "https://...rest.marketingcloudapis.com/"}

but still get error creating ETClient . I do not need to pass in appSignature because I'm using clientId and clientSecret.